# Multiple condition in shell script not working

Tags: shell

I am trying to write a shell script to check the status of my VPN connections. The logic I want is ***If the VPN is down, it should bring up the tunnel. If that failed to do so it should send an email with relevant details.***

The issue I am facing here while executing the script is trying to bring up all the connections regardless of the status of the VPN's.

===========================================================================

## Below is my script

```
dt=$(date -d "+8 hours")

for i in $(cat /root/vpn_list)
do
  echo $i
  vpn=`ipsec status $i|grep 'ESTABLISHED'`
  result=$(echo $vpn)

  if [[ "$result" != "" ]];then
    echo "$dt: $vpn is established"
  elif
    ipsec up $i
    echo "$dt: $vpn is up"
  then
    if [[ "$result" != "" ]];then
      echo "$dt: $vpn is established"
    else
      echo "$i VPN is broken | Please check immediately"|mailx -r 'xxxx@.com' -s smtp='xxxxxxx' -s smtp-use-starttls -ssmtp-auth=login -s smtp-auth-user='xxxx@.com' -s smtp-auth-password='xxxx' -s ssl-verify=ignore xxxx@.com -s "$i VPN is Down ($dt)"
    fi
  fi
done
```

I would appreciate if someone could tell me what I missed here. Thanks

Comment: I have indented your code in order to make its logic appear. Please tell us the problem you are facing: what is happening against your expectations? Anyway the syntax of the `elif` statement is not clear.

Comment: Hi @PierreFrançois, my expectation is to only start if a VPN's connections appear to be down. But what's happening now is even though a connection is up and running. The script still starting the connection again. In simple word, the script just starting all the connections.

**Below is what my expectation**

1) Check if the status of the VPN Tunnels
2) If the tunnel is down, it should bring up the tunnel
3) If failed to bring up, it should send an email with details

Could let me know what's wrong with my syntax of `elif`

Comment: The syntax of `elif ... fi` is the same as `else if ... fi; fi`, so I am expecting a test after `elif` and on the same line.

Comment: Don't complicate your code: `result=$(echo $vpn)` is quite the same as `result=$vpn` (except that you shrink repeated spaces into one space).

Comment: I can't get the logic. You test twice `[[ "$result" != "" ]]` without updating `$result` between the tests. This can't be what you want to do.

Comment: Try to make a MWE (minimal working example), without referring to files which content is unknown to us, like `/root/vpn_list`. V.gr., you could replace the expression `for i in $(cat /root/vpn_list)` by a list corresponding to the content of that file, like `for i in vpn1 vpn2 vpn3 vpn4`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @PierreFrançois.

The test after `elif` I would like to do is to `ipsec up vpn1`.
The second test `[[ "$result" != "" ]]` I would like to re-check if all the VPN's are up. If no, then send an email to me. 

The content of `/root/vpn_list` is just the vpn connections name.

Comment: Sample outcome of the script. The mention connections were up. But still, the script executing `ipsec up vpn1` from the script

vpn1
generating QUICK_MODE request xxxxxxxxxx [ HASH SA No KE ID ID ]
sending packet: from IP1 to IP2 (316 bytes)
received packet: from IP1 to IP2 (316 bytes)
parsed QUICK_MODE response xxxxxxxxxx [ HASH SA No KE ID ID ]
connection 'vpn1' established successfully
Mon Mar  2 15:45:01 UTC 2020: vpn1[131535]: ESTABLISHED 7 hours ago, IP1...IP2 is up